How to do a cleanup of conda base environment? (not the conda clean for unused packages)
I was recently struggling with the issue of having to remove a host of libs like pandas, plotly, etc., that I accidently installed in the base environment (I was installing it within my jupyter notebook and didn't realize which env I was using).
There are also a few pip installs I did a while ago, so I am just looking to clean out of my base env, keeping only the pertinent pakgs without breaking the whole thing.
I've come to one conclusion which is to use conda remove in this manner:
conda remove -n base --all --keep-env
or
activate base env
conda remove -all --keep-env
But I am a bit reluctant to try it because I do not want to break the environment. Does anyone have any insight or has used this option?

setup a new venv there , install all packaging in existing env and then do the experiment
